# Uploading a File to SharePoint Online using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm really new to Microsoft Graph API, I created a script using powershell to get reports from Microsoft 365 and it is being saved on my drive (`c:\temp\reports.xlsx`).

After it is being saved i wish to upload it to SharePoint online. On reading the docs, Microsoft says to do the following request,

```
PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
```

I then tried to apply it to my use case and this was my request:

```
function RestMethod {
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$Request,

        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$RequestMethod,

        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$Body
    )

    $Headers = @{
        Authorization = "$($global:RequestToken.token_type) $($global:RequestToken.access_token)"
    }
    $RestResults = $null 
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

    try {
        $RestResults = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Request -Headers $Headers -Method $RequestMethod -ContentType "application/json"
    } catch {
        Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
        Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
    }

    return $RestResults
}



$upLoadRequest = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenant.sharepoint.com/drive/items/Test:/$($File):/content"

$upLoadResults = RestMethod $upLoadRequest 'PUT'
```

The `$File` variable contains `c:\temp\reports.xlsx` the directory where my excel file is saved on getting the reports. The `Test` in my Url is a folder I created in `Documents` on my Site. But while doing the request I get this:

```
StatusCode: 400 
StatusDescription: Bad Request
```

Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of changes:

- in the provided question file is incorrectly addressed, since it
  needs to be uploaded under `Test` folder of `Documents` library, it
  could be addressed like this:
  `/v1.0/sites/{tenant}.sharepoint.com/drive/root:/Test/reports.xslt:/content`
  refer [Addressing resources in a drive on OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/addressing-driveitems?view=odsp-graph-online#:~:text=OneDrive%20supports%20addressing%20files%20and,encoding%20of%20any%20path%20segments.) for a more 
  details
- the content of file for [`Upload`  endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)  *is missing* , it could be 
  provided via [`-InFile` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-RestMethod?view=powershell-7&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-3.0), e.g. `Invoke-RestMethod -InFile $path ...`

Here is a minimal example:

```
$access_token = "--access token goes here--"
$path = "--path to local file, e.g. c:\data\report.xlsx--"

$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{tenant}.sharepoint.com/drive/root:/{folder}/{filename}:/content"
$headers = @{'Authorization' = "Bearer $access_token" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Put -InFile $path -ContentType 'multipart/form-data'
```