# Upload a file into sharepoint using Graph api by PowerShell scripting

Tags: powershell, file-upload, microsoft-graph-api, shared-libraries, azure-ad-graph-api

I am not able to find the exact step by step procedure. And please let me know the different possibilities.I had wrote a script to create a temporary token in Powershell scripting to connect to graph api and couldn't able to code further. can anyone please help me with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload the file to `SharePoint` by calling this API:

```
Put /v1.0/sites/{tenant}.sharepoint.com/drive/root:/Test/reports.xslt:/content
```

This is a simple example:

```
$access_token = "--access token goes here--"
$path = "--path to local file, e.g. c:\data\report.xlsx--"

$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{tenant}.sharepoint.com/drive/root:/{folder}/{filename}:/content"
$headers = @{'Authorization' = "Bearer $access_token" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Put -InFile $path -ContentType 'multipart/form-data'
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62283355/uploading-a-file-to-sharepoint-online-using-microsoft-graph-api), hope it can help you.